# How do I use span around text in Elm?

Tags: html, elm, markup

How can I write the following markup in Elm?

```
<p>Here is <span class="red">some text.</span></p>
```

Comment: here's a good tool to do that for you: https://mbylstra.github.io/html-to-elm/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact answer seems to be a bit of both of the first two answers

```
someText : Html Msg
someText =
    p []
        [ text "Here is "
        , span [ class "red" ] [ text "some text." ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
p []
    [ (text "hi there, ")
    , span [] [ text "I'm a span" ]
    ]
```

This creates the HTML

```
<p>hi there, <span>I'm a span</span></p>
```

See running example at [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/6NhqLygjvjVa1).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted, but one solution is to put spans around the other text as well.

```
someText : Html Msg
someText =
    p []
        [ span [] [ text "Here is " ]
        , span [ class "red" ] [ text "some text." ]
        ]
```